# codeigniter redirect to different controller

Tags: codeigniter, controller

I am trying to direct the user to my main page when the user is authorized. I am doing the user check in my login_check controller and add `$this->load->view('main');` The page can be load but the site address in the main page still show

> http://myprojectname/login_check

but I want it to show

> http://myprojectname/main.

Do i have to create a new 'main' controller and load the view? It sounds redundant to me. Here is my code.

part of my `login_check.php`

```
private function _user_check()
{
    $this->load->model('user_query');  //load my model
    $result=$this->user_query->query($this->input->post('username'),$this->input->post('password'))             

    if($result)  //the user is in DB
    {
        $data['view']='main'; 
        $this->load->view('include/template', $data);
        //the address bar shows http://myproject/login_check in main page       

    }else{  //the user is not in DB

        $data['view']='login';
        $this->load->view('include/template', $data);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

First of all, you are doing a very poor job of checking if the user is authenticated (just passing username/pass to model isn't best, should process / check it before sending to model).

You can make redirects easily by including the helper 'URL' and simply use:

```
redirect('/controller/method');
```

or in a real world example:

```
redirect('/main');
```

[**Reference Link**](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html)

Comment: When you said "process / check" before sending to model, your mean form_validation? If so, I already did it on my other part of the code. Do I need to do mysql_real_escape_string?  I thought Codeigniter already apply it since I am using $this->input->post. Thans.

Comment: No you are fine then, CI takes care of all that if you use **Active Queries**, however if you write the SQL query yourself you need to use `$this->db->escape()` to escape your say 'username' or 'password' just in case (never hurts to be extra prepared)

Comment: When redirecting this way, the Url gets an index.php added after the site domain, I managed to remove index.php suffix using .htaccess but while using this redirection method its coming back again

Comment: @ClainDsilva that is probably because you didn't remove it from your CONFIG... it is clearly defined there, remove it to NOT have it appended.

Comment: @Jakub Thanks for the info.. I am curious why they have that in there? They could deploy it without showing index.php and just navigate with controllers ?

Comment: @ClainDsilva the obvious reason they leave it in is because unless you have apache `mod_rewrite` enabled, you cannot just remove the `index.php`

Comment: @Jakub Sir, as far as I understand.. When using the redirect(), it wont carry any error message right? So how should I put/show the error message if I am in another controller?(from event controller to login controller)

Answer (score 0):

There is another way but similar to redirect(), if your controller is Rest controller

[restserver](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver)

You can use rest client in another controller to call methods on the server controller

[restclient](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restclient)

Answer (score 0):

```
redirect('controller/function');
```

For example you can have 
`redirect('auth/login');` with routes as

```
$route['auth/login'] = 'auth/auth/index';
```